# How to compile a program in C with IAR for msp430x5438A when i get the following error?

Tags: c, msp430, iar

i am using IAR for msp430xf5438A and when i am trying to compile my program i get an the following error: Internal Error: [TaInstr::Validate]: Instruction does not match requirement. what can i do to solve the this error? thanx!

Comment: Did you try contacting IAR tech support ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an internal error in the compiler, it is issued when one part of the compiler emits an instruction that it shouldn't have.

If you have the latest version of the compiler, make sure you report this to IAR so that they can fix it. If not, I suggest that you upgrade the compiler.

If you need to continue with the compiler you have, you could try to change the optimization levels or other settings. Alternatively, try to figure out which code triggers the problem and rewrite it.

If you can reduce the problem to a small sample, add it to your question and I'll try to suggest ways to rewrite the code.